# Turn a switch Off or On on the basis of another switch state

Tags: ios, xcode, uiswitch

How can I turn a switch off inside a different switch?
Here's an example - When the isMale switch is turned on, turn off the isFemale switch.

```
- (IBAction)isMale:(id)sender {
       if ([sender isOn]) {

             //TURN isFemale SWITCH OFF

       }
       else {
            ...
       }
 }
```

and

```
- (IBAction)isFemale:(id)sender {
       if ([sender isOn]) {

            //TURN isMale SWITCH OFF

       }
       else {
            ...
       }
 }
```

I've been reading the Apple development docs but cannot find anything about changing a switch inside another switch.
Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all you need to create `IBOutlet` of both `UISwitch` in your header `.h` file

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *isMale;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *isFemale;
```

then in your `IBAction` do as follow.

```
- (IBAction)isMale:(id)sender {
   if ([sender isOn]) {

         [_isFemale setOn:NO animated:YES];

   }
   else {
        // do what you want.
   }
}
- (IBAction)isFemale:(id)sender {
   if ([sender isOn]) {

        [_isMale setOn:NO animated:YES];

   }
   else {
        //do what you want
   }
}
```

remember to connect both of your `IBOutlet` to respective objects in your `UIViewController`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is simple example which you need

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
 {
    [super viewDidLoad];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [_btnMale setOn:YES animated:YES];
    [_btnFemale setOn:NO animated:YES];

 }


 - (IBAction)btnMaleClick:(id)sender
 {
     if ([sender isOn])
     {
        [_btnFemale setOn:NO animated:YES];
     }

 }

 - (IBAction)btnFemaleClick:(id)sender
 {
    if ([sender isOn])
    {
       [_btnMale setOn:NO animated:YES];
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

in swift 5.1 (Xcode 11) use

```
       [switchPass .setOn(false, animated: true)]
```

Answer (score 0):

here is how to switch button state in swift for future reference

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    btnMale.setOn(true, animated: true)
    btnFemale.setOn(false, animated: true)

}

@IBAction func btnMaleClick(sender: UISwitch){
    if sender.on{
        btnFemale.setOn(false, animated: true)
    }
}
@IBAction func btnFemaleClick(sender: UISwitch){
    if sender.on{
        btnMale.setOn(false, animated: true)
    }
}
```